# how to load label data presented in raster format into Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I want to use CNN network to segment 2 objects (binary: "0: object not present, 1: object present") into shapes but I have an issue with data. The train data is 150 images and in "jpg" format and the ground truth (label data) is also 150 images of "png" rasters of 0 and 1 (resulting in black white images).

Now the question is how to load this hybrid of train images and label images in Keras/Tensorflow and if there`s a dummy example and/or demonstration on how to do that in Python, I would be grateful.

Comment: do you mean to say the labels are not text (0 or 1) and themselves images? also i assume there is no mention of 0 or 1 in the label images filenames?

Comment: @AtulShanbhag yes you are correct. The labels are not a text but rather images so for each training image there's a label image and that label image is a raster of 0 and 1 (0 means the feature absent and 1 means the feature present). In other words the label images are masks of the feature exist in each training image

Comment: My assumption, that the filenames don't have a 0 or a 1 so we can figure out it's class from the filename, is that correct?

Comment: @AtulShanbhag yes. Essentially labels are just the training images masked according to the feature shape .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define one generator for reading the input images and another one for reading the labels using the [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) class and its [`flow_from_directory()`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) method, and then combine these two generators in a single generator. Just make sure the directory structure and (order of) file names of input and label images are the same:

```
data_image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(...)
data_label_gen = ImageDataGenerator(...)

image_gen = data_image_gen.flow_from_directory(image_directory,
                # no need to return labels
                class_mode=None,
                # don't shuffle to have the same order as labels
                shuffle=False)

image_gen = data_image_gen.flow_from_directory(label_directory,
                color_mode='grayscale',
                # no need to return labels
                class_mode=None,
                # don't shuffle to have the same order as images 
                shuffle=False)

def final_gen(image_gen, label_gen):
    for data, labels in zip(image_gen, label_gen):
        # divide labels by 255 to make them like masks i.e. 0 and 1
        labels /= 255.
        # remove the last axis, i.e. (batch_size, n_rows, n_cols, 1) --> (batch_size, n_rows, n_cols)
        labels = np.squeeze(labels, axis=-1)

        yield data, labels

# ... define your model

# fit the model
model.fit_generator(final_gen(image_gen, label_gen), ...)
```

Comment: can you explain little bit you solution as to what's going on exactly. because what confuse me is the label data being essentially the training images with object shape as mask (for example we are detecting  cars so cars pixels are assigned  to 1 and the surrounding area to 0)

Comment: @aminevsaziz Are you familiar with `ImageDataGenerator` in Keras? It is used to load image batches (on the fly) from numpy arrays or from hard disk. Now, in my answer I have defined two generators one for the input images and another for their corresponding labels which are images as well. Together, they read the training data from the hard disk and generate batches of training data. Then you can use `fit_generator` method to fit your model using a generator. Further, if the labels are "png" files, then when you read them the values would be in range [0,255], so the division by 255 in answer.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. Before I assign your answer as solution is there any way to handle/load the data (training and labels) in tensorflow without keras api. If there's a way please included in the answer above.

Comment: @aminevsaziz There is [Tensorflow dataset api](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets). However, I am not familiar with it that much so I can't include it in my answer (at least, until I have a good understanding of it).

Comment: thank you. I will assign your answer as solution and I hope someone can add up something helpful without keras api.